# How to get previously selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">Actions</option>
    <option>Create Subset</option>
    <option>Goto</option>
    <option>End</option>
</select>
```

I'm showing popup for whatever option user selects, and on pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> or on clicking the close button, the popup will disappear.

Now, suppose user selected "Create Subset" option and filled appropriate data into that popup. Currently "Create Subset" will be there in select box.

Now if user changed the option to "Goto" (i.e. there will be "Goto" in the select box) and pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>, hence the popup will disappear *but there will still be "Goto" in the `<select>` box!*

So my question is: **Is there any way to change the select box option to the previously selected option when the user hits <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click the close button?**

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript you've written so far?

Comment: You should take trace of your user action on select box, then restore previous; there is not native method to do this

Comment: If you recorded that value at the start of the open popup script it should be feasible...

Comment: good use of formatting. Could give +1 but for the lack of effort shown

Comment: Hey guys, I found the solution. Here it is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bh4M3/1/). Please let me know if there's any corrections. Thank you all !!!

Answer (score 2):

First you gotta give your option's some values and your select box - some id:

```
<select id="yourselect">
    <option value="Actions" selected="selected">Actions</option>
    <option value="Create Subset">Create Subset</option>
    <option value="Goto">Goto</option>
    <option value="End">End</option>
</select>
```

Then bind a change event to listen to your checkbox changes and remember the current and previous options that were selected:

```
$("#yourselect").on("change", function() {
    if( $(this).data("selected") ) {
        $(this).data( "prev-selected", $(this).data("selected") );
    }

    $(this).data( "selected", $(this).val() );
});
```

After that, when user presses Esc or click Cancel button, you need to restore the option

```
if( $("#yourselect").data("prev-selected") ) {
    $("#yourselect")
       .find( 'option[value="' + $("#yourselect").data("prev-selected") + '"]' )
       .prop( "selected", true );
}
else {
    $("#yourselect").find( "option:eq(0)" ).prop( "selected", true );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but somehow I found my solution. Here it is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bh4M3/1/). Tell me if anything's wrong in my code.

Comment: @Jalay i think you will have a problem if you select an option and push the Close button twice. I've modified your code to fix that problem. See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyvk/zU8SN/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not added relevant code. Here i created reference [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DmFXZ/218/) . When user selects option from select box, it will display popup, and on close of popup it will update select. Not sure if this is what you need, let me know.

```
<div id='selectPopup'>
    previous selected <input type='text' value='' id='selected'/>
    <form name='test'>
        <select id='inptPAN' name='inptPAN'>
            <option value='1'>item 1</option>
            <option value='2'>item 2</option>
            <option value='3'>item 3</option>
            <option value='4'>item 4</option>
            <option value='5'>item 5</option>
            <option value='6'>item 6</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    // this function is triggered as soon as something changes in the form
    $("select[name='inptPAN']").change(function () {
        //console.log('found change');
        $("#selected").val($(this).val())
        selectDialog('Pan', 'You had selected, Text: ' + $(':selected', this).text() + ' And Value : ' + $(this).val());
    });

    // Esc button event  to close pop up.

  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if(event.which === 27) {
               previousSelected = $("#selected").val();
                    $("#inptPAN").val('1');
                    // or enable below line to set previous selected
                  //$("#inptPAN").val(previousSelected); 
                    $('<div></div>').dialog("close");
        }
    });

    function selectDialog(title, text) {
        return $('<div></div>').append(text)
            .dialog({
            resizable: true,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "CLOSE": function () {
                   previousSelected = $("#selected").val();
                    $("#inptPAN").val('1');
                    // or enable below line to set previous selected
                  //$("#inptPAN").val(previousSelected); 
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but somehow I found my solution. Here it is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bh4M3/1/). This's what I needed :)